# Django Rest Framework quickstart Page not found 404

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to do a quickstart tutorial from https://django-rest-framework.org.

And this is my `urls.py`

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework import routers

from main.views import MovieViewSet, CommentViewSet

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'movies', MovieViewSet)
router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

and when I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/` I get

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/movies/
Using the URLconf defined in movie_api.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

^$ [name='api-root']
^\.(?P<format>[a-z0-9]+)/?$ [name='api-root']
The current path, movies/, didn't match any of these.
```

The viewsets and serializers are implemented as in tutorial.
Am I tired and not seeing something?

Comment: Your message doesn't match your urls.py. What's the root urls file ?

Comment: I believe that this is root urls.py file, this is next to settings.py

Comment: It just doesn't match the listed urls you get from the 404

Comment: What is it that doesn't match?

Answer (score 0):

When I have changed `ViewSet` to `ModelViewSet` it is working.